# Java stream, filter, and then do something with resulting collection

Tags: java, java-stream

**Goal**

```
final List<T> listOfThings = ...;

listOfThings.stream()
    .filter(...) // returns a Stream<T>
    .then(filteredListOfThings -> {
        // How do I get here so I can work on the newly filtered collection
        // in a fluent way w/out collecting the result to a variable?
        // For example, if I need to process the elements but don't 
        // care about them in their current form outside this chain.
    });
```

**Problem**

In English, given a list of something, I'd like to stream the list, filter it, and then operate on the *entire filtered result*. I can accomplish this with optional but it's not clean IMO:

```
final List<T> listOfThings = ...;

Optional
    .of(listOfThings.stream()
        .filter(...) // returns a Stream<T>
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .map(filteredListOfThings -> {
        // I'm here, now, but would like to not have to wrap it in an Optional<T>
    });
```

It'd be cool if there was a `then` or similar method on a `Stream<T>` which returns `Stream<T>` to allow for further chaining, which allows me to work with the entire set of results within the lambda without declaring an outside variable.

Comment: What is your goal with the filtered collection?

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: you can do `map` operation on filtered stream `listOfThings.stream().filter(--).map(--)`

Comment: Assign it to a variable, do something with the variable.

Comment: Are you looking for `flatmap`?

Comment: There is no fluent way to do it like you want.  Make a variable; call it `filteredListOfThings` -- a name you would've had to invent anyway.  Seriously: make it a variable.  Don't wrap it in an `Optional`.

Comment: @JacobG. The goal is to operate on it within a chained lambda, fluently.

Comment: @YCF_L The return type of this method would be `Stream<T>` to allow further chaining.

Comment: @Deadpool `map` operates on each element in the `Stream<T>` individually, I'm looking for a way to "catch up" and access all members of the `Stream<T>` up to that point.

Comment: @DonHosek No, `flatMap` would be useful for flattening a stream of streams, but not what I need here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks, that's what I'm asking -- is it possible, and it sounds like the answer is "no", unless I wrap it in an `Optional<T>`, which is silly IMO.

Comment: Maybe I didn't word it well. Think of how in Javascript we can do `new Promise(...).then(...).then(...).finally(...) ...`, etc. The part I was looking for in Java (and yes, I realize they are different constructs), is to `then` on a Stream to "catch up" and provide a lambda to handle all elements.

Answer (score 5):

Don't make it more complicated than it needs to be.

Assign the result of the `collect` to a variable, then operate on that variable:

```
List<T> filteredListOfThings = ... .collect(toList());

// Now use filteredListOfThings.
```

`filteredListOfThings` will always have a value, even if it's the empty list, so there's no point in using `Optional`.

And there's not much syntactic difference between `filteredListOfThings` being a lambda parameter and it being an explicit variable; but you have more flexibility in what you can do whilst processing it (returning from the methods, throwing checked exceptions etc).

Comment: Perfectly valid, just another aspect: when you want „to do something with the whole list“ means that not each element gets processed individually, but need to know the other elements (like for min, max or distinct) you can use the Stream.reduce method.

Comment: Sure, but the question is asking is there such an API to enable this fluently? Looks like there really is not. IMO there is a difference between using a lambda and an outside variable, as far as the code is concerned, creating an outside variable shouldn't be necessary in this case. (And by "outside" I mean outside of the chained `Stream` calls.)

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to stream the list, filter it, and then operate on the entire filtered result.

Note that the stream can be infinite as well ;)

So getting the infinite list of results is not a good idea.

Basically streams are lazy and applying an intermediate operations to stream without having a terminal operation does nothing:

For example the following code prints nothing:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("hello","how","are", "you").filter(this::startsWithH)

private boolean startsWithH(String elem) {
  System.out.println("Filtering element " + elem); 
  return elem.startsWith("h");
}
```

Now, when you do apply a terminal operation, it will still work element-by-element usually:

Example of execution:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("hello","how","are", "you")
.filter(this::startsWithH)
.map(String::toUpperCase)

stream.collect(toList());
```

This example yields the following execution chain:

1. filter("hello")
2. map("hello")
3. filter("how")
4. map("how")
5. filter("are")  <--- filtered out, no call to map will be done
6. filter("you")  <--- filtered out, no call to map will be done

But if so, you can't really operate on the "whole" stream in the example provided in this question (ok, there are stateful operations that must work on the whole stream, like **sort**, but its an entirely different story).

In other words if you want to get the data as a collection you should, well, collect the data. It won't be a stream anymore.

For this, you should use `.collect()`. And if you do have an infinite stream, don't forget to call `limit` beforehands ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I fully understand that Streams are not necessarily finite, but by question about a `then` option to gather up the results is no different than when you `collect` a stream (with/without a limit). It's just a fluent helper.